# I cant click on a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Its my first time using selenium and I am developing a project to download a meeting attendence on Microsoft Teams, The code works well and i can get to the screen that I need to make de download [The screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JtBn.png), now I just need to click on "Baixar", but it doesn't work,

My code:

```
BAIXAR = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')
WebDriverWait(navegador, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BAIXAR)).click()
```

[A print from de inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9xgW.png)

I need to click on the button "Baixar"

Answer (score 0):

The wait statement with EC.element_to_be_clikable() will return you boolean (True/False). Hence you can't apply .click() with Boolean.

Instead use the same wait statement with EC.presence_of_element_located

objelement=WebDriverWait(navegador60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((BAIXAR))

objelement.click()

Comment: Still dont working :( Cell 
     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)


     41 WebDriverWait(navegador, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PARTI)).click()
     43 #WebDriverWait(navegador, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BAIXAR)).click()
     44 
     45 #navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Baixar']").click()
---> 48 J = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BAIXAR))
     49 J.click()

Comment: Instead of EC.element_to_be_clickable use EC.presence_of_element_located